# Angular ng eject command - webpack customizarion

Tags: angular, webpack

I  want to load `webpack` generated files either in `head` or at some other placeholder.

Current Page structure as per `ng cli`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
         .....
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
 </head>
 <body>
   <app-root></app-root>
   <script></script> ---- all angular generated scripts
 </body>
</html>
```

I need it to be like as below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
         .....
   <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
   <script></script> ---- all angular generated scripts
 </head>
 <body>
   <app-root></app-root>
 </body>
</html>
```

To achieve my desired result, i have used `ng eject` command and i have `webpack.config.js` file in my project root.

In webpack config file, i have edited **HtmlWebpackPlugin** and updated inject flag as below:

```
"inject": 'head',
```

With above change, i have got scripts in head but then i am getting error that `app-root` is not a known element.

Answer (score 0):

it is not a known element because in head it will load before this node exists.